# If $0 \le t_1 < ... < t_r \le m, mn < q$ and $t_i r \equiv c + c_i \mod q, 0 \le c_i \le n$ for all $i,$ prove $0 \le c_1 + c_3 - c_2 \le n.$

Tags: number-theory

> If $0 \le t_1 < ... < t_r \le m, mn < q$ and $t_i r \equiv c + c_i \mod q, 0 \le c_i \le n$ for all $i,$ prove that $0 \le c_1 + c_3 - c_2 \le n.$

$m, n, c, q, r$ are constants. I have reduced quite a tricky and difficult problem to showing the following claim (and some similar claims where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ is replaced with $c_i, c_j, c_k, i<j<k$). Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to continue. We need to show $c_2+c_3 \ge c_1$ and $c_2 + c_3 \le n+c_1$ using the strange condition that $mn < q.$ I haven't found out how this condition plays a role, and I'm very certain that I won't solve the problem unless I figure out how to use it.

I also have no idea how I'm going to use the fact that $0 \le t_i \le m.$ What I can say is that $a = t_2 - t_1, b = t_3 - t_2$ are positive and $(ar, br) \equiv (c_2 - c_1, c_3 - c_2) \mod n.$ But because modular arithmetic destroys any traces of sign or size, I can't conclude anything about the sign of $d = c_2 - c_1, e = c_3 - c_2,$ only that $-n \le d, e, d+e \le n.$ What should I do?

It would suffice to rule out the possibility $c_1 < c_2, c_3$ or $c_1 > c_2, c_3,$ but a triplet $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$ could satisfy the main inequality and still fall into one of these cases. $mn < q$ might've motivated us to use the pigeonhole principle, but the fact that we're looking at just $6$ numbers $t_1, t_2, t_3, c_1, c_2, c_3$ means there's not enough stuff for the holes!